# How to bypass the 255 char limitation in MSWord Search&Replace using OLE

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole, replace

I am using (in a Delphi win32 application) OLE to perform search and replace in Word Documents.

THe user prepares a file with some textual tags enclosing them in "{" and "}" and saves the file.

Something like

> Dear {NAME},
>
> I want to tell you {WHAT_I_DID_LAST_WEEK}

Of course `NAME` and `WHAT_I_DID_LAST_WEEK` are DB fields that can be longer than 255.

So now by using Search and replace with OLE i get a STRING PARAMETER TOO LONG error (it seems 255 is the longest string usable there).

Is there an easy way to get rid of the problem?

Some home made solutons I thought of are:

1) truncate to 255 (good one ;) ) may be appending "..." at the end

2) for every "tag" that requires a replace of more than 255 chars I could first insert more tags like `{WHAT_I_DID_LAST_WEEK_1}{WHAT_I_DID_LAST_WEEK_2}{WHAT_I_DID_LAST_WEEK_N}` and then replace 255 chars at a time

(1) is a quick solution, at least user doesn't recieve the error, but of course it is not very good

(2) would probably work but it is a workaround, I would prefer another solution.

May be another solution is not use OLE Serach&Replace but use another function.

Comment: Can't the same be done using Mail Merge?

Comment: @Cosmin: MS Word mailmerge is a pain. Document variables through automation is much easier. And possibly easier than OP's solution. Though his is possibly much easier to understand for users.

Comment: Can't the OP replace those user-defined fields with document fields first and then fill document fields with proper data? I'm just asking, never did Word automation.

Comment: @Marjan Venema Yes, the simple approach I have is higly appreciated by any kind of users. Moreover if I change it I should them ask to reivew thousands of already existing templates. Anyway could you redirect me to some link that explains your Document variable idea?

Comment: @Cosmin: Yes, that would certainly be possible. And I think (!) it should help with the character limit. user193655: Ah, if you have a moment or two or three. Don't have a link, but I do have a D6 app that uses this approach. Need to dig it out and "tweak" it a bit to make it presentable. Will try and do it today, but don't hold your breath, it may take until Sunday... :-)

Comment: The nice work Marjan Venema did has been posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791590/alternatives-to-search-and-replace-to-use-for-telling-to-an-application-where-to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we use AWordApp.Selection.TypeText(strValue) and loop for replacing tags that have value string longer then 255 chars ...

```
 var
  AWordApp: OLEVariant;
 ...
 AWordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
 ...

if (Length(strValue) >  255) then
 begin
  bFound := AWordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(params...);
  while bFound do
   begin
    AWordApp.Selection.TypeText(strValue);
    bFound := AWordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(params...);
   end;
 end;
```

regards

Comment: This is somehow my solution (2). Correct?

Comment: yes if you mean "would probably work but it is a workaround, I would prefer another solution." :) You don't have to split strings.

Comment: ok got it. It a very good suggestion I already implemented and it works. Thanks.